# VNC connection drops between Raspberry pi and Windows 10 when I bridge WiFi with Ethernet on Windows settings

Tags: raspbian, ssh, vnc

My intention is to bridge the Internet connection from my PC to raspberry pi through Ethernet, but I always lose SSH connection. I even tried to let the Raspberry pi connect to the WiFi while I  am using SSH, it connected but no Internet connection. But when I connect it to the screen and use mouse and keyboard it connects normally to the Internet. 
  Sorry for bad English, and I do appreciate any help.

Comment: How is your internet connection currently configured? What model of RPi?